# How can I load css file using source function of twig?

Tags: css, twig

I'm twig beginner, I Want to get the CSS file content and not the path to be clear, this file is located in:-

```
Bundle/Ressources/public/css/'~var~'/main.css
```

var is a dynamic variable, so I used the source function of twig, but it seems that I don't point to the right path. Here is my code:

```
 <style>
 {{ source('/Bundle/Resources/public/css/'~var~'/main.css',  ignore_missing = true)  }} 
</style>
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You are not using correct notation for the path.

In your case, if your bundle is named *FooBundle*, you should use:

```
{{ source('@FooBundle/Resources/public/css/'~var~'/main.css',  ignore_missing = true)  }}
```

If your file's location was inside `Resources/views/` for example `Resources/views/foo/bar.html.twig` you could use even shorter variants:

```
{{ source('FooBundle:foo:bar.html.twig',  ignore_missing = true)  }}
```

or:

```
{{ source('@Foo/yourTemplate.html.twig',  ignore_missing = true)  }}
```

See also: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html